# How to read or write an I/O port in arm64?

Tags: io, operating-system, arm, port, arm64

I was trying to write one byte to an I/O port, but I am failing finding the correct instructions in the instruction set of arm64 aarch64 architecture.

To do the same thing in i386, I'd do something of similar:

```
void dbg_io_write_8(uint16_t port, uint8_t val)
{
    asm volatile (
        "outb    %%al, %%dx;"
        /* Outputs  */ : /* None */
        /* Inputs   */ : "a" (val), "d" (port)
        /* Clobbers */ : /* None */
        );
}
```

And, for reading:

```
uint8_t dbg_io_read_8(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t val;

    asm volatile (
        "inb     %%dx, %%al;"
        /* Outputs  */ : "=a" (val)
        /* Inputs   */ : "d" (port)
        /* Clobbers */ : /* None */
        );

    return val;
}
```

This code refers to the `NS16550` serial port.

Comment: arm does not have an I/O space and memory space.  It just has one address space.  The peripherals are mapped into that space and you use the load and store instructions using the address defined by the chip vendor (ARM is not the chip vendor btw, they only are an ip supplier to the chip vendor like other ip suppliers).

Comment: what specific  chip are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arm64 has no concept of I/O ports.

If you are both a CPU vendor and a SoC designer, and have a very good reason for it, you might opt to map a peripheral to a (set of) custom system register(s). In that case you'd talk to the peripheral via `mrs`/`msr`.

In all other cases, you memory-map it to some physical address. So you access it through simple loads and stores.

Comment: Bad news, thanks. I wonder how a gdbstub for arm64 may work while doing `target remote:1234`. "1234" is a port. I'd like to answer to myself looking for the code, but I am failing again finding a stub for arm64 :)

Comment: Please, @siguza, may you deepen a bit the sentence "In all other cases, you memory-map it to some physical address"?

Comment: I thought you were writing a kernel module. gdb ports are just standard TCP/IP ports. Like any other userland program, gdb has to use syscalls and defer to the kernel if it wants to use those.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at outb(): https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/include/asm/io.h#L235

eventually the outb() access is converted to memory access using += PCI_IO_VIRT_BASE (=0xfee00000)