# Accessing portio using uio framework from Linux user-space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How to use/access portio from Linux user-space using uio(port) framework of Linux?

I have a 32bit (pci)register that I want to access from linux user-space on a Aarch64 platform. This address is not page-aligned. My driver uses uio framework of Linux and by declaring `uio_info.mem[]`, I could mmap() from user-space and access the page region(4K) that contains this register. This way a process have access to adjoining registers as-well that I am not ok with.
**My goal is let the user-space process to have access to the intended register only**. uio framework also allows portio by declaring `uio_info.port[]`. This way from `/sys/class/uio/uioX/portio/port0` I could see porttype, size, start but this is physical address that I assigned in driver. I am not clear how does this help accessing the physical portio region in user-space? Can I translate this address into something that is accessible in user-space?

If I declare `uio_info.port[]`, I cannot mmap(), doing so will return with Invalid argument(22). Looking into the `drivers/uio/uio.c`, `uio_find_mem_index()` returns -1 as `uio_info.mem[]` is not declared. Does this mean that by all means I must declare `uio_info.mem[]` along with `uio_info.port[]` both pointing to the same address even if my intent is to use as portio? My understanding is for the same memory, either port[] or mem[] should be used. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read or write an I/O port in arm64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538526/how-to-read-or-write-an-i-o-port-in-arm64)